# changing Date format in query

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

in some part of my program , I want to run a sql query and have the result which is a date like : %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S

```
SELECT MAX(created_at)
FROM HOT_FILES_LOGS
WHERE FILE_NAME = 'test'
```

date in created_at column is stored like 04/03/2021 15:45:30 ( it is fulled with SYSDATE)
but when I run this query, I get just 04.03.21

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: _date in created_at column is stored like 04/03/2021 15:45:30_ Actually, it isn't. (Just a side note and not essential to your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `TO_CHAR` with appropriate format mask:

```
select to_char(max(created_at), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') as created_at
from hot_files_logs
where file_name = 'test'
```

Comment: What about a link to the documentation regarding the different date format models? And maybe also an explanation regarding the default date format model?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not store dates or timestamps in any display format, they are stored in an **internal structure**, every date in every Oracle database since at least 8i and probably earlier. This structure consists of [7 1-byte integers](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals#date) (timestamps in a similar but larger structure). How the date is displayed or a string converted to a date is controlled the specified date format string in the to_char or to_date function or if no format string given by the [NLS_DISPLAY_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/NLS_DATE_FORMAT.html#GUID-FC23EEEE-AA9F-4B3C-8CBB-888C9C0CA27F) setting. To get a gimps at the internal settings run the following:

```
 create table td( d date);
 insert into td(d) values(sysdate); 
 select d "The Date" , dump(d) "Stored As" from td;
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2a1c31c5fb7464a2f065be061b59b15c). The last used format is not practical but strictly demonstrable. Well I guess you could use it to seed a repeatable random sequence.